# Javascript : getting function name with this.name

Tags: javascript, closures

I am executing following code

```
function Person(name, age){
 this.name = name || "John";
 this.age = age || 24;
 this.displayName = function(){
  console.log('qq ',this.name);
 }
}

Person.name = "John";
Person.displayName = function(){
    console.log('ww ',this.name);
}

var person1 = new Person('John');
person1.displayName();
Person.displayName();
```

getting following output :

```
qq  John
ww  Person
```

I am not getting how am getting this.name = Person in second console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That comes from `Function.name` as explained in the [JS MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

> A Function object's read-only name property indicates the function's
>   name as specified when it was created, or "anonymous" for functions
>   created anonymously.

```
function doSomething() {}
doSomething.name; // "doSomething"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the desired output, change the property `name` to `name1`

```
function Person(name1, age){
 this.name1 = name1 || "John";
 this.age = age || 24;
 this.displayName = function(){
  console.log('qq ',this.name1);
 }
}

Person.name1 = "John";
Person.displayName = function(){
    console.log('ww ',this.name1);
}

function main() {
    var person1 = new Person('John');
    person1.displayName();
    Person.displayName();
}
```

The output :

```
qq  John
ww  John
```

Answer (score 1):

The name property returns the name of a function statement.

When you are calling function as Person.displayName();  & try to use "this.name". it will return name of the function